# How to design a table of product bid price history on dynamodb?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I have a bidding website, each user can bid his own price for a product.
The schema:

```
productId: S // the product, probably the Hash key
day: S // for example: "2016-08-05"
userId: S // the user id that offer his bid for this day
bidPrice: N
```

I don't know how to design the table(s), i need to be able to a query like this:

`SELECT userId, bidPrice FROM product-history WHERE productId = "sony-tv" AND day between "2016-01-05" AND "2016-05-05"`

However, the *day* field cannot be a range key because i can't store multiple rows per *productId+day*

I also need to be able to update the bidding price for a user... something like:

`UPDATE product-history SET price = 12 WHERE productId = "sony-tv" and day="2016-01-05" and userId = "steve"`

What the best way to approach this?

Comment: If you're giving SQL syntax, why aren't you using a SQL database?

Comment: It's only demonstration of which type of queries i want to be able todo.

Comment: I understand. I'm simply asking why you have tagged your question with DynamoDB when you could use your Amazon services to setup a MySQL database to perform these queries

Comment: Because i think it's a simple query, i don't have to make advanced joins, i am going to have a 25 million rows every day, so i am going to store a lot of data... i am prefering dynamo because i don't need to handle the IT Solutions by my self.

Comment: By the way, as i think of it more and more, maybe you are right and mySql can be a better solution for this scenario... I will think about it

Answer (score 0):

Here is the design for the above use case.

Hash Key : User Id

Range Key : Product Id

Each user can bid on a product id.

This design allows an user to bid on multiple product ids as well.

**Create global secondary index (GSI) on product id and date:-**

You can use the GSI to query the database using product id and date. While creating the GSI, there is an option to include only few attributes or all the attributes from main table.

[GSI Link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.html)

**Limitation:-**

The user bidding history of a product id would not be available. For example, if an user is changing the bidding on a product id multiple times, it would not be available on this data model.